# How can I remove the function call ambiguity from a Lemon grammar?

Tags: c++, parsing, state-machine, lalr, lemon

I have the following lemon grammar (simplified from the real grammar):

```
%right ASSIGN .
%nonassoc FN_CALL .

program ::= expression .
expression ::= expression ASSIGN expression .
expression ::= function_call . [FN_CALL]
expression ::= IDENTIFIER .


function_call ::= expression LPAREN RPAREN . [FN_CALL]
```

I'm not able to fix the shift-reduce conflict in the following state:

```
State 3:
      expression ::= expression * ASSIGN expression
  (1) expression ::= expression ASSIGN expression *
      function_call ::= expression * LPAREN RPAREN
                    ASSIGN shift  1
                    LPAREN shift  4
                    LPAREN reduce 1   ** Parsing conflict **
                 {default} reduce 1
```

My thought is that the problem was the ambiguity between a=(b(c)) and (a=b)(c), but I would have thought that giving the function call a higher precedence than assignment would fix it. Any ideas what could be the case?

Answer (score 0):

First and biggest point: a shift-reduce conflict is *rarely* a real problem. As such, this may well be something you don't need (or even care) to fix.

Second point: unfortunately, it looks to me like you may have over-simplified your grammar. Just for example, the grammar (as you've posted it) looks like both `a=(b(c))` and `(a=b)(c)` should be rejected outright (the only place you've specified an LPAREN, it has to be followed *immediately* by an RPAREN). What you've posted doesn't give us enough to guess about what's likely to be wrong with the real grammar.

Comment: I only parenthesized to show the ambiguity; the two possible parse trees I was trying to show are the ones where the top level expression is a function call whose expression is "a=b" and the tree where the top level expression is an assignment whose first expression is an identifier and whose second is a function call.

The problem shows up even in this tiny grammar though; there's a conflict if you compile this as is.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
program ::= assignment .

assignment ::= expression ASSIGN assignment .
assignment ::= expression .

expression ::= expression LPAREN RPAREN .
expression ::= IDENTIFIER .
```

It lets you assign to function calls (which is unusual), but so did your original grammar.  I realize this is just a part of a larger grammar.

Comment: That would do it though but yeah the fact that I'd have to rewrite the entire grammar to encode precedence rules sort of makes me a little bit worried there.

Comment: You won't have to rewrite all of it.  You could probably separate it into just binary, prefix, and suffix ops easily enough, and use the %right %left declarations on the binary parts.